Is it technically feasible for iOS app to support programmatic creation of subscriptions such that one user can subscribe to multiple users?
I’m developing an app similar to Patreon where creators can decide if they want to charge either $5 or $10 a month for users to be able to view their content (each creator can only have one subscription price defined)
I came across information that the only way users can subscribe to multiple subscriptions (each from a different creator) in one app, those subscriptions need to be defined in their own Subscription Group. However, it seems that Subscription Groups need to be manually, pre-defined through an online portal and go through an approval process. So the number of Subscription Groups created would have to match the number of creators.
This wouldn’t scale because I need the ability for those subscriptions to be created on the fly when new creators sign up.
Am I understanding that correctly? If so, how can I get around this?
More information about Subscription Groups https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/
